# Unable to install ubuntu sdk

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

While installing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk,` I am facing this 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

`ubuntu-sdk` depends on `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova`. Latter needs `cordova-ubuntu-2.8`, `cordova-ubuntu-2.8-dev`, `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu`, `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova-common`.

This unmet dependancy problem could have been aroused, because `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova` cannot be installed.

So run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova cordova-ubuntu-2.8 cordova-ubuntu-2.8-dev qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova-common
```